# Why is Pandas not converting NumPy array's "V" dtype to object anymore in a Dataframe?

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dtype

Until Pandas 1.3.5, when I convert a dict of NumPy arrays into a Dataframe, one of the NumPy arrays with dtype 'V' gets converted into a Dataframe column with dtype object.

Since 1.4.0, the dataframe's column is `|V8`. I can't find anything in the release notes about this change so I am wondering if it a bug on my side.

```
data = { 'column name' : np.array([b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x40',
                            b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x40'], dtype=np.dtype('V'))}

df = pd.Dataframe(data)
```

for 1.3.5, `df.dtypes` was :

```
column name          object
```

since 1.4.0, it is:

```
column name            |V8
```

why?

Comment: At least in recent enough numpy, the array itself is `'|V8'